# How apply external docker image in aws code build?

Tags: docker-image, aws-codebuild, .net-4.6.2

I am developing a webapi applciation which targets .net framework 4.6.2.
In order to run, i also need msbuid 15 along with visual studio 2017 build tools.

I found a docker image for this from Microsoft. Below if the URL
https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework

As I am very new to this docker, i don't know how to use in the code build.
I added like below image

[image: My Code build environment setup]

When i run, i got the error like below image
[image: Build Error]

Please help on this. I tried to use any docker images already built, as I don't know about docker

Comment: What registry are you using? Your registry URL should look more like an actual url.

Comment: I used https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework this only. I don't know is this correct

Comment: So in that link you mentioned you'll see that when you pull images you do it in the form of <repository_name>/<image_name>:<image_tag>. An example is mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/samples:dotnetapp, where the repository name is mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework and the image name/tag is samples:dotnetapp.